# Easy way to iterate over two structures consecutively with a foreach loop

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, c++17

Is there an easy way to achieve this design pattern in c++17?

```
std::set<uint32_t> first;
std::set<uint32_t> second;

for (uint32_t number : JoinIterator<uint32_t>(first, second)) {
   <DO SOMETHING WITH number>
}
```

This would replace the following code:

```
std::set<uint32_t> first;
std::set<uint32_t> second;

for (uint32_t number : first) {
   <DO SOMETHING WITH number>
}

for (uint32_t number : second) {
   <DO SOMETHING WITH number>
}
```

All of the search results I have found are about looping over both structures in parallel, not looping over the structures consecutively.

Comment: I would make `<DO SOMETHING WITH number>` a function and call it in two separate loops.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `views::concat` from [range-v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/):

```
for (uint32_t number : views::concat(first, second)) {
   <DO SOMETHING WITH number>
}
```

This only works with ranges that have the same underlying type (which is true in this example).

---

In Boost (i.e. range-v2), this is spelled [`boost::range::join(first, second)`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/join.html).

Since it's not apparent from the Boost documentation directly, this function is found in `boost/range/join.hpp`

Comment: Thanks! Trying to solve it without 3rd party libs except Boost if possible (though a pure std lib solution is preferred)

Comment: @TheBat Added the Boost solution. There's nothing like this in the standard library (although you could of course implement this, but it's non-trivial).

Answer (score 0):

How about using for_each with boost?

```
#include<iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <boost/iterator/zip_iterator.hpp>

int main(){
    std::set<uint32_t> first = {1,2,3};
    std::set<uint32_t> second = {4,5,6};
    std::for_each(
        boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(first.begin(), second.begin())), 
        boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(first.end(),second.end())), 
        [](const boost::tuple<uint32_t,uint32_t>& t) {
            std::cout << t.get<0>() << " : " << t.get<1>() << std::endl;
        });
    return 0;
}
```

Not sure if it'll suit your needs but is pretty useful in some cases

Comment: I think OP wants [1,2,3,4,5,6]... not [(1,4),(2,5),(3,6)]?

Comment: zip_iterator loops in parallel, not consecutively.